# Какие темы допустимы, а какие "оффтопик" (не по теме форума)

Tags: обсуждение, поддержка, статус-завершено

Зашел посмотреть [в справку](https://rus.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), о чем можно спрашивать на "Русском языке" и что я вижу?

> Stack Overflow на русском - это сообщество профессиональных разработчиков программного обеспечения, энтузиастов программирования и системных администраторов.
>   Какие вопросы можно задавать?
>
> Здесь можно задать любой вопрос, относящийся:
>
> - к конкретной задаче программирования - коду, алгоритмам, реализации алгоритмов на определенных языках программирования;
> - к инструментам для разработки - языки программирования, среды, операционные системы, пакеты программ, фреймворки, библиотеки;

И так далее. Так какие же вопросы здесь допустимы?

---

What questions are on-topic on this site? The help section resembles "Stack Overflow in Russian" on-topic help.

Comment: Шаблон не перевели.))) Я к сожалению,  пропустил весь процесс локализации, хотя мог бы быть полезен, но вынужден был отдыхать от компа. Вот результат )))

Comment: Тут - в связи с появлением новых пользователей - вопрос снова встал. Поскольку откосить от решения мне не удалось, придется таки сделать. Дня через три постараюсь.

Comment: До сих пор в справке, к сожалению, просто копия текста с другого сайта.

Comment: Если если это мне, то да, я снова обманул, поскольку начал, но тут же бросил. Понял, что совершенно не понимаю запросов пользователей, особенно новых. Настолько специфические у них представления о назначении ресурса и правилах поведения на нем.  А потребность вроде как и сама отпала.

Comment: просто я долго не понимал, можно ли задать вопрос, который хочу задать. Попробую написать вариант правил к концу праздников и предложить здесь для осбуждения

Comment: А Вы насколько опытный пользователь тут и вообще на SE?

Comment: А лучше всего - просто задайте свой вопрос,  ничем не рискуете.

Comment: Вопрос я уже задал.

Comment: я разместил вариант правил для обсуждения на сайте "Русский язык мета"

Comment: Сылочку бы дали.

Comment: http://meta.rus.stackexchange.com/questions/76/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-faq-%D0%91%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%83-%D0%B2-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D1%83%D1%8E-%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%8C

Answer (score 3):

Реально на "Русском языке" можно задавать любые вопросы, к русскому языку или литературе относящиеся. Кроме провокационных политических (на тему "какой язык главнее" и "паруски нада пейсать вУкраине и Таллинннн"), очевидных домашних заданий и полного бреда. Не знаю, как это сформулировать в справке, но это уже не моя забота.

Comment: Как мне кажется, @Artemix ожидал ответа, подобного [этому](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/a/154/6). Пожалуйста, попробуйте придать вашим идеям и мыслям некую подобную форму.

Comment: "Я столько не выпью". ))) @Artemix, если Nicolas Chabanovsky прав, то я не понял вашего вопроса. Мне казалось, вы интересуетесь исключительно глюком локализации движка. Но если ощибаюсь, и это для пользы дела, я попробую сформулировать этот "ЧаВо для чайников"... Но на это уйдет изрядно времени. Не мое это хобби FaQ'и писать

Comment: Вопрос возник в связи с этим постом: [Мнения о “Грамматике Пор-Рояля”](http://rus.stackexchange.com/q/35700/176629). Поскольку связь вопроса с русским языком не вполне очевидна, я решил почитать справку. Вопрос оформления ответа здесь меня не очень беспокоит, но официальную справку все-таки кто-то должен поправить.

Comment: да, согласен, этот вопрос неуместен. Ни по декларативной направленности ресурса, не по сложившейся практике. Добро бы еще там об общей грамматике речь шла, а то вообще о каком-то непонятном труде. Но я думаю, что это ясно без всяких пояснений.

Comment: И с претензией к "справке" тоже согласен. Я попробую, коли уж админ просит, но не беру на себя смелость обещать, что сделаю это быстро и  хорошо. К тому же у меня намечается длительный мозговой штурм совсем другой проблемы...