# Неожиданно, все вопросы сайта «Русский язык» — оффтопик

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено

**Этот вопрос - сообщение об ошибке**, а не предложение определять тему. Дублем не является.

Читаем раздел справки: [На какие темы здесь можно задавать вопросы?](https://rus.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

> Здесь можно задать любой вопрос, относящийся:
>
> - к конкретной задаче программирования - коду, алгоритмам, реализации алгоритмов на определенных языках программирования;
> - к инструментам для разработки - языки программирования, среды, операционные системы, пакеты программ, фреймворки, библиотеки;
> - к проектированию, использованию и администрированию баз данных;
> - к настройке физических, виртуальных серверов, серверов-приложений, серверов баз данных, веб-серверов, файл-серверов, средствам их
>     настройки, мониторинга и этих автоматизации процессов;
> - к реальной проблеме, встречающейся на практике, решение которой можно изложить кратко в паре абзацев, и которая уникальна для
>     разработки программного обеспечения и профессионального
>     администрирования IT систем.

Похоже, что сайт «Русский язык» нуждается в собственном разделе справки. =)

Для этого нужно определить, что же входит в рамки вопросов по теме. Это происходит вот в этом вопросе: [Какие темы допустимы, а какие "оффтопик" (не по теме форума)](https://rus.meta.stackexchange.com/q/16/177015)

Answer (score 0):

Все, что относится к русскому языку. 
Вы не вопросы задавайте, а предлагайте свою версию, коли уж беретесь рассуждать о том, что допустимо - и что нет. Я в свое время отказался, ибо не хочу навязывать свою точку зрения.

И помнится, повтор вопроса. Обсуждалось уже. Сейчас попробую найти.

Держите. 
[Какие темы допустимы, а какие "оффтопик" (не по теме форума)](https://rus.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16)